# How to make the port free; already used by Drupal ?

Tags: tomcat, drupal

I am attempting to install Drupal 7 as a localhost on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 and also have Tomcat 7.0.53 loaded for another program. How would I go about changing the port used by Drupal, since Tomcat is using port 8080?

Comment: How are you installing Drupal? Using `apt-get install drupal7`?

Comment: "sites/default.settings.php"? also see: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7

Comment: Please specify the web server you are using to run Drupal7, answer will be different if you run it under Apache, Lighttp, NGINX or other). And the default port it is listening too.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion its easier to change the port that Tomcat is using. Locate the `server.xml`  in Tomcat installation folder.  Change the 8080-port to whatever you like. For example :

`<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />`